Zephyr ping returning ethernet interface with IP 0.0.0.0
I am building an application to ping my pc from my microntroller.
The ping does not work, when I verify the ethernet connection I am using, it always returns IP 0.0.0.0.
This is my code:
static void iface_callback(struct net_if *iface, void *user_data) {
    struct net_if_addr *if_addr;
    char buf[NET_IPV4_ADDR_LEN];

    // Check if the interface is up
    if (net_if_is_up(iface)) {
        LOG_INF("PING. Interface is up.");
        // Get the IPv4 address of the interface
        if_addr = net_if_ipv4_get_global_addr(iface, NET_ADDR_PREFERRED);
        LOG_INF("PING. Interface Index: %d", net_if_get_by_index(iface));
        if (if_addr) {
          net_addr_ntop(AF_INET, &if_addr->address.in_addr, buf, sizeof(buf));
          LOG_INF("PING. Checking interface with IPv4 Address: %s", log_strdup(buf));

          struct net_linkaddr *link_addr = net_if_get_link_addr(iface);

          if (link_addr) {
            LOG_INF("PING. Interface ID: enx%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
                    link_addr->addr[0], link_addr->addr[1], link_addr->addr[2],
                    link_addr->addr[3], link_addr->addr[4], link_addr->addr[5]);
        
        // Optionally, also print it in standard colon-separated format for clarity
            LOG_INF("PING. MAC Address: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
                    link_addr->addr[0], link_addr->addr[1], link_addr->addr[2],
                    link_addr->addr[3], link_addr->addr[4], link_addr->addr[5]);
          }

          LOG_INF("PING. Interface pointer (address): %p", iface);
              
          // Compare with the target IP address
          if (strcmp(buf, "10.131.17.2") == 0) {
            LOG_INF("PING. Found the correct network interface.");
            *(struct net_if **)user_data = iface;  // Store the correct interface in user_data
          }
          LOG_ERR("PING. Failed to find the correct network interface");
          *(struct net_if **)user_data = iface; //Store any interface it found
          LOG_INF("PING. Found interface with IPv4 Address: %s", log_strdup(buf));
        }
    }else{
      LOG_ERR("PING. Interface is down with IPv4 Address: %s", log_strdup(buf));
    }
}

void ping(const char *ip_addr_str) {
    LOG_INF("PING.Trying ping to IP: %s", log_strdup(ip_addr_str));

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    struct net_if *iface = NULL;  // Interface pointer
    int sock, ret;
    char recv_buf[128];  // Buffer to receive ping reply
    static uint16_t ping_seq_num = 0;
    char buf[NET_IPV4_ADDR_LEN];

    // Iterate over all network interfaces
    net_if_foreach(iface_callback, &iface);

    if (iface == NULL) {
        LOG_ERR("PING.Failed to find the correct network interface");
        return;
    }

    // Create an IPv4 RAW socket for ICMP
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    if (sock < 0) {
        LOG_ERR("PING.Failed to create socket, error %d", errno);
        return;
    }
    LOG_INF("PING.Ping socket successfully open");

    // Set up the destination address
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip_addr_str, &addr.sin_addr);

    if (net_if_is_up(iface)) {
        LOG_INF("PING.Ethernet interface is up.");
    } else {
        LOG_ERR("PING.Ethernet interface is down.");
        close(sock);
        return;
    }

    struct net_if_addr *if_addr = net_if_ipv4_get_global_addr(iface, NET_ADDR_PREFERRED);
    if (if_addr) {
        net_addr_ntop(AF_INET, &if_addr->address.in_addr, buf, sizeof(buf));
        LOG_INF("PING.Ethernet interface IPv4 Address: %s", log_strdup(buf));
    } else {
        LOG_ERR("PING.No IPv4 address assigned to the correct interface.");
        close(sock);
        return;
    }
    //check_network_interfaces();
    ping_seq_num++;

    // Send ICMP Echo Request (ping) using the correct interface
    LOG_INF("PING.Sending ping request to %s", log_strdup(ip_addr_str));
    ret = net_icmpv4_send_echo_request(iface, &addr, ping_seq_num, PING_ID, 1);
    if (ret < 0) {
        LOG_ERR("PING.Failed to send ping request, error %d", ret);
        close(sock);
        return;
    }
    LOG_INF("PING.Ping request successfully sent");

    // Set socket receive timeout
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = PING_TIMEOUT_MS / 1000;
    timeout.tv_usec = (PING_TIMEOUT_MS % 1000) * 1000;
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));

/*
    // Wait for an ICMP Echo Reply
    while (true) {
        ret = recv(sock, recv_buf, sizeof(recv_buf), 0);
        if (ret > 0) {
            // Parse the ICMP packet
            uint8_t icmp_type = recv_buf[20];  // ICMP type is the 21st byte
            uint8_t icmp_code = recv_buf[21];  // ICMP code is the 22nd byte
            uint16_t icmp_id = (recv_buf[24] << 8) | recv_buf[25];  // ICMP identifier
            uint16_t icmp_seq = (recv_buf[26] << 8) | recv_buf[27]; // ICMP sequence number

            // Check if it's an ICMP Echo Reply (type 0, code 0) and matches our ID and sequence
            if (icmp_type == 0 && icmp_code == 0 && icmp_id == PING_ID && icmp_seq == ping_seq_num) {
                LOG_INF("PING.Ping reply received from %s", log_strdup(ip_addr_str));
                break;
            }
        } else if (ret == -1 && errno == EAGAIN) {
            LOG_ERR("PING.Ping timeout.");
            break;
        } else {
            LOG_ERR("PING.Failed to receive ping reply, error %d", errno);
            break;
        }
    }
*/
    // Clean up
    close(sock);
    LOG_INF("PING.Ping socket closed!");
}


This is my log file
[00:00:22.533,782] [0m<inf> Modem: Succeeded to queue event: Socket read[0m
[00:00:22.606,597] [0m<inf> Modem: PING.Ping socket successfully open[0m
[00:00:22.606,597] [0m<inf> Modem: PING.Ethernet interface is up.[0m
[00:00:22.606,628] [0m<inf> Modem: PING.Ethernet interface IPv4 Address: 0.0.0.0[0m
[00:00:22.606,628] [0m<inf> Modem: PING.Sending ping request to 10.131.17.2[0m
[00:00:22.607,086] [1;31m<err> net_arp: Gateway not set for iface 0x20001a7c[0m
[00:00:22.607,147] [0m<inf> Modem: PING.Ping request successfully sent[0m
[00:00:22.607,208] [0m<inf> Modem: PING.Ping socket closed![0m
[00:00:22.607,238] [0m<inf> Modem: Received response: OK[0m
[00:00:22.607,238] [0m<inf> Modem: SendCommand: 9[0m
[00:00:22.607,238] [0m<inf> Modem: Sending: AT+QCFG="simeffect",0[0m
[00:00:22.707,397] [0m<inf> Modem: PING.Trying ping to IP: 10.131.17.2[0m
[00:00:22.707,427] [0m<inf> Modem: PING. Interface is up.[0m
[00:00:22.707,427] [0m<inf> Modem: PING. Interface Index: 0[0m
[00:00:22.707,458] [0m<inf> Modem: PING. Checking interface with IPv4 Address: 0.0.0.0[0m
[00:00:22.707,458] [0m<inf> Modem: PING. Interface ID: enx0004a3010203[0m
[00:00:22.707,458] [0m<inf> Modem: PING. MAC Address: 00:04:a3:01:02:03[0m
[00:00:22.707,489] [0m<inf> Modem: PING. Interface pointer (address): 0x20001a7c[0m
[00:00:22.707,489] [1;31m<err> Modem: PING. Failed to find the correct network interface[0m
[00:00:22.707,489] [0m<inf> Modem: PING. Found interface with IPv4 Address: 0.0.0.0[0m
[00:00:22.707,519] [1;31m<err> Modem: PING. Interface is down with IPv4 Address: [0m
[00:00:22.714,050] [0m<dbg> Modem: Response: 
                                0d 0a 4f 4b 0d 0a                                |..OK..           [0m

I assume my code is not returning the right interface, however, I am using the  net_if_foreach(iface_callback, &iface); function to iterate all the ethernet interfaces and I still only get an interface with  0.0.0.0 IP address.
I know the connection should work, because I am able to ping my microcontroller from my machine
m@m:~$ ping 10.131.17.1 3149
PING 3149 (0.0.12.77) 56(124) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.131.17.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.29 ms
64 bytes from 10.131.17.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.31 ms
64 bytes from 10.131.17.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.27 ms
64 bytes from 10.131.17.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=3.30 ms
64 bytes from 10.131.17.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=3.28 ms
64 bytes from 10.131.17.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=3.25 ms
64 bytes from 10.131.17.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=3.30 ms
64 bytes from 10.131.17.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=3.33 ms
64 bytes from 10.131.17.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=4.08 ms

